# Unable to scrape website with beautifulsoup in python to extract article text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a list of urls using beautifulsoup in python to extract text of the articles from the urls.

while in case of one url1 = https://www.bandt.com.au/bolster-common-state-merge-to-form-new-agency-group/ I am able to obtain the text of the article, in the case of another url2 = https://ians.in/pr-wire-detail/biophotas-inc-announces-new-vice-president-of-marketing-08-08-2023 i am unable to get the article text.

when I right click on the text of url2 and click on the inspect option I see that the page shows a line that says "you need to enable javascript to run this app" I am not sure if somehow this is a problem.

I am using mac and use chrome browser.(Chrome Version 118.0.5993.117 (Official Build) (x86_64))

Here is the code i used

================

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url1='https://ians.in/pr-wire-detail/biophotas-inc-announces-new-vice-president-of-marketing-08-08-2023'

url2='https://www.bandt.com.au/bolster-common-state-merge-to-form-new-agency-group/'

r=requests.get(url1, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

soup
```

==================

The output from soup in case of url1 shows the text of the article.
The output from soup in case of url2 does not show the text of the article.

Q: How do I scrape url2 to get the text of the article?

Comment: Have you looked at the text you get back?  If not, why not?  That should be step number 1.  The second page consists of nothing but Javascript.  The page contents are built dynamically.  You can't use `requests` for that.  You'll have to use something that interprets Javascript, like Selenium or `requests_html`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I looked at the text it puts back.  It does not output the article text in case of url2. in case of url1 it does output the article text which i then extract.

Comment: Thank you I will try Selenium and requests_html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you see on the page is loaded from external URL. To get it you can simulate the Ajax request:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://cms.iansnews.in/api/pr-newswire/biophotas-inc-announces-new-vice-president-of-marketing-08-08-2023/?language=english"

html_text = requests.get(api_url).json()["results"][0]["content"]
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```

Prints:

```
USTIN, Calif. , Aug. 8, 2023 /PRNewswire/ -- BioPhotas Inc., manufacturers of the award-winning Celluma SERIES of light therapy devices,

...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like magic.

Comment: Where can i run ajax requests. I have a series of such links. Can I do it in python?  please let me know. I have quickly googled but it is not pointing to exactly converting the urls to the kind that you have here (api_url)

Comment: You basically need to reverse engineer the Javascript on the site to figure out what it's actually fetching.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes that is what I do in case of normal urls. But some of these(javascript dependent) urls are not being read at all by beautiful soup. The solution that Andrey has suggested is working. I. need to figure how how to run ajax request and get all urls in the form that beautiful soup can read.